# Max, len, split Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to find all combinations of A,B repeated 3 times.
Once I've done this I would like to count how many A's there are in a row, by splitting the string and returning the len.max value. However this is going crazy on me. I must have misunderstood the len(max(tmp.split="A")

Can anyone explain what this really does (len returns the length of the string, and max returns the highest integer of that string, based on my split?) I expect it to return the number of A's in a row. "A,B,A" should return 1 even though there are two A's.

Suggestions and clarifications would be sincerely welcome

```
import itertools
list = list(itertools.product(["A", "B"], repeat=3))

count = 0;

for i in list:
    count += 1;
    tmp = str(i);
    var = len(max(tmp.split("B")))
    print(count, i, var)
```

Comment: Why not separate it into three separate steps if you're unclear? Then you'd *know* what `tmp.split` gives you, what the `max` of that is and why `len` is apparently not what you expected.

Comment: @Dartmouth er, no. `max` will return a string here, and `len` will give you the length of that string. Calling `len` on an integer would be a TypeError.

Comment: BTW, it's a bad idea to shadow the built-in `list` type with a variable named `list`, especially when you want to use the  `list` type constructor in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find groups of identical elements in an iterable. `groupby` generates a sequence of (key, group) tuples, where `key` is the value of the elements in the group, and `group` is an iterator of that group (which shares the underlying iterable with `groupby`. To get the length of the group we need to convert it to a list.

```
from itertools import product, groupby

for t in product("AB", repeat=3):
    a = max([len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(t) if k == "A"] or [0])
    print(t, a)
```

**output**

```
('A', 'A', 'A') 3
('A', 'A', 'B') 2
('A', 'B', 'A') 1
('A', 'B', 'B') 1
('B', 'A', 'A') 2
('B', 'A', 'B') 1
('B', 'B', 'A') 1
('B', 'B', 'B') 0
```

We need to append  `or [0]` to the list comprehension to cover the situation where no "A"s are found, otherwise `max` complains that we're trying to find the maximum of an empty sequence.

#### Update

Padraic Cunningham reminded me that the Python 3 version of `max` accepts a default arg to handle the situation when you pass it an empty iterable. He also shows another way to calculate the length of an iterable that is a bit nicer since it avoids capturing the iterable into a list, so it's a bit faster and consumes less RAM, which can be handy when working with large iterables. So we can rewrite the above code as

```
from itertools import product, groupby

for t in product("AB", repeat=3):
    a = max((sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(t) if k == "A"), default=0)
    print(t, a)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot!

Comment: For python3 you can use a default value with max, `max((sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(t) if k == "A"),default=0)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Oh yeah! I keep forgetting about that very useful feature. But I'll keep my code as it is, just in case Python 2 people want to use it...